# C File Descriptor for polling task completion status of worker thread

Tags: c, multithreading, events, polling, epoll

I am having a C project which has 2 threads, `main_thread` and `worker_thread`. Below pseudocode explains about it.

```
TASK g_task[MAX_TASK];
worker_thread()
{
    do {
        listen_for_task on g_task
        do_task(0);
    } while(0);
}

int post_task(msg)
{
    post on g_task
    /* I am planning for a kind of file descriptor to return from here */
    /* on which main thread polls along with sock_fd */
    return fd;
}

main_thread()
{
    int sock_fd;

    /* sock_fd listens on well known TCP port for msgs from clients */
    /* Using epoll */
    ev.events = EPOLIN;
    ev.data.fd = sock_fd;
    epoll_ctl(epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, sock_fd, &ev);
    do {
        nfs = epoll_wait(...)
        if (nfs > 0) {
            /* I read the msg from from sock_fd and post to g_task */
            post_task(msg)
        }
    } while (0);
}
```

On `main_thread` I am waiting on a tcp socket for msgs from various clients. I am processing and posting the work to be done to another thread `worker_thread`.

Now I want the `worker_thread` to notify `main_thread` after finishing each task posted to it. I am expecting the event should come to a new file descriptor. That means I am expecting `post_task` should return a new `fd` which I can add to `epollfd`. And `worker_thread` should wakeup it.

Any suggestion for achieving this is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention using epoll, you must be using Linux. Which means you can use [`eventfd()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html).

Basically, your `post_task` function creates a new eventfd descriptor for each thread and the main thread monitors it for readability in epoll. The thread then writes a 64 bit integer to its descriptor when it's done. The main thread then wakes from epoll, sees the event is readable, reads a 64 bit integer from it, and does whatever it needs to do now that it knows the associated thread is done with a task. (On non-linux systems you can get a similar effect using [`pipe()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html); I've written code with an event creation function that switches between the two depending on what OS is being targeted)

If you need to pass more information than just a "I'm done" status, I like using a Unix domain datagram socket created with [`socketpair()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socketpair.2.html) and reading/writing structs with all the needed data. If you include a thread id, all threads can even share the same socket.